# Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating... (<UIAlertController:>)

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I'm getting the above error on a view controller, although I have the exact same code in another view controller, where I'm not getting the error:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:  { 
        action in 
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
        }
        ))
    if self.presentedViewController == nil{
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to declare alertController as a class property, and then modify my viewDidAppear as follows:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if self.alertController.actions.count == 0 {
            self.alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:  { action in UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
                }
                ))
            if self.presentedViewController == nil {
                self.presentViewController(self.alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
}
```